# поддержка формата в webP, есть ли на 2022 год смысл использовать jpg/png?

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, frontend

поддержка формата в webP, есть ли на 2022 год смысл использовать jpg/png? IE летом его не будет, а все остальные браузер его полностью поддерживают...

Comment: Только вы можете знать, из каких браузеров посещаются ваши сайты, соответственно, только вы можете решить, имеет или не имеет.

Comment: многие сайты уже отдают в webp.

Answer (score -1):

Всё зависит от проэкта, и задач, котырые есть в проэкте. Если есть необходимость использовать только WebP - используем именно его. Если такой задачи не стоит, не вижу смысла отказываться от всем знакомым jpg и png. Смысл всегда есть использовать и поддерживать старые форматы, если делать проэкт для себя, можно использовать и WebP.